# mysql how to shorten count 5 results

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make 5 count results from mysql, and I wanna ask, maybe exist shorten code for all results? My code now:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM bets WHERE status='Waiting'");
$row_cnt1 = $result1->num_rows;

$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM bets WHERE status='Win'");
$row_cnt2 = $result2->num_rows;

$result3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM bets WHERE status='Lost'");
$row_cnt3 = $result3->num_rows;

$result4 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM bets WHERE status='Void'");
$row_cnt4 = $result4->num_rows;
```

And I display with this code:

```
    <b>Total wins:</b> <?php echo $row_cnt1;?> <br />
<b>Total voids:</b> <?php echo $row_cnt2;?> <br />
<b>Total losts:</b> <?php echo $row_cnt3;?> <br />
<b>Total waiting:</b> <?php echo $row_cnt4;?> <br />
```

Comment: Count rows or display them ? `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` will do the count.

Comment: `select count(*) from bets group by status`?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to limit the result of the query to 5? Because you could simply put `LIMIT 5` at the end of the query? Or am I understanding the question wrong

Comment: sorry for mistakes, example: In mysql I have 4 row with status - 'waiting', and I wanna to display: Waiting: 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT status, COUNT(*) as number FROM bets WHERE status IN ('Waiting','Win','Lost','Void') GROUP BY status");
```

You will have 4 rows, with 2 columns, from one query.

Note: If you don't have anymore statuses, the WHERE statement is unnecessary.

You can display your results like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<b>Total ' . $row['status'] . ': ' . $row['number'] . '</b><br/>';
}
```

Comment: You have a typo, you forgot to add `GROUP BY status`

Comment: Why I'm getting error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in" :(

'$query = "SELECT status, count(*) FROM bets WHERE status IN ('Waiting','Win','Lost','Void') GROUP BY status";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query);'

echo $result2;

Comment: Okey, thanks man, but why It only write Total status: but no display numbers?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the COUNT() function if you group like this:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) AS numForStatus
FROM bets
GROUP BY status;
```

So, this will display a table like this:

```
|  status  | numForStatus |
+----------+--------------+
|  waiting |      5       |
|  win     |      4       |
|  lost    |      3       |
|  void    |      2       |
```

That's one way to simplify your query, and can hopefully make your output a little easier as well.

Comment: @user1221081 I'm not the best with PHP, but your question was about how you can simplify your query so that's what I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It uses `GROUP BY` clause in `SQL` query and a while loop to shorten your code.

```
    <?php
    $qry = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT, status FROM bets  GROUP by status";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $qry );
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array(result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {

    ?>
      <b>Total $row['status']:</b> <?php echo $row['CNT'];?> <br />
    <?php 
   }
   ?>
```